# error in calling code behind C# method from javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, code-behind

I have the following java script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function taskDone(taskID) {

              alert(taskID);

              var btn = document.getElementById('btn-taskDone-' + taskID);
              var icon = document.getElementById('task-icon-' + taskID);

              btn.style.color = '#8F9199';
              btn.onclick = "";
              btn.style.cursor = 'default';
              icon.src = "./../Images/Icons/doneTask.png";                  

              '<%=setDone(123)%>'

          }

</script>
```

and the following code behind method

```
 public Boolean setDone(int taskID)
    {
        BO.taskDao myTask = new BO.taskDao();
        Boolean success = myTask.setDone(1, taskID);
        return success;
    }
```

and i want to call setDone method from javascript function and passing taskID instead of 123,
but i don't now how to do that. and i didn't know why server automatically run this line of script  '<%=setDone(123)%>' when the page loaded and without call taskDone "JavaScript" function

Comment: you prefer using ajax or doing a postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things.

First, you need to decorare your method with the `WebMethod` attribute and also make it `static`. Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Boolean setDone(int taskID)
{
    BO.taskDao myTask = new BO.taskDao();
    Boolean success = myTask.setDone(1, taskID);
    return success;
}
```

Now, make sure you have a `ScriptManager`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then in JavaScript, you call it by doing:

```
PageMethods.setDone(taskID, onSuccessMethod,onFailMethod);
```

Whilst also having success and fail methods (passed in above):

```
function onSuccessMethod(success) {
    //query success
}

function onFailMethod() {
    //check failure
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All server inline code such as `<%=setDone(123)%>` is executed during generation of the page, and it's position in JavaScript is merely because you placed it there.

You can use inline code to pass server side data ***to*** JavaScript in this fashion.

If you want JavaScript to execute server side code, you can use several techniques. As well as WebMethods described by mattyTommo you can put a value in a input box, and then call a button click for a server side button and have the server side code read the content of the input box.